# How to filter data from array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, filter, reduce

Hi can anyone help me create an array of objects where the array has the `object` which has the highest version of a particular event id

Here is my array:

```
[{ version: 1, eventId: 12, id: 22 },
 { version: 2, eventId: 12, id: 23 }, 
 { version: 3, eventId: 12, id: 24 }, 
 { version: 1, eventId: 13, id: 25 }, 
 { version: 2, eventId: 13, id: 26 }]
```

Expected result

```
[{ version: 3, eventId: 12, id: 24 }, { version: 2, eventId: 13, id: 27 }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you want:

```js
const ar = [{ version: 1, eventId: 12, id: 22 },
 { version: 2, eventId: 12, id: 23 }, 
 { version: 3, eventId: 12, id: 24 }, 
 { version: 1, eventId: 13, id: 25 }, 
 { version: 2, eventId: 13, id: 26 }];
 
const res = Array.from(ar.reduce((a, c) => {
    if (a.has(c.eventId)) {
        if (c.version > a.get(c.eventId).version) {
            a.set(c.eventId, c)
        }
    } else {
        a.set(c.eventId, c)
    }
    return a;
}, new Map()).values())


console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

sort by the highest and then use `filter`

```js
array=[{ version: 1, eventId: 12, id: 22 }, { version: 2, eventId: 12, id: 23 }, { version: 3, eventId: 12, id: 24 }, { version: 1, eventId: 13, id: 25 }, { version: 2, eventId: 13, id: 26 }, { version: 3, eventId: 13, id: 27 }]
vn=array.sort((a,b)=>b.id-a.id)[0].version
res=array.filter(o=>o.version==vn)
console.log(res)
```